# Button Click Iterate Through Images

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and I was trying to figure out how to move between images. My goal is to change code for the image placeholder in the html so that on every button click, it changes to the next image. I've figured out how to change one image to another (getElementById("mainImage").src="image2.jpg";) but I need to be able to now get to "image3" on the next button click. I assume I need to use variables, but I have no idea how to get this to work...

Comment: What HTML are you working with? What's the structure of your DOM? Can you show what you've already got, with a live demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), or similar? Are the images/`src`s in the DOM/HTML somewhere, or in an array within the JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some `var key = 0;` before your scripts and then in your script give action for click event

```
var image = "image" + key + ".jpg";
getElementById("mainImage").src= image;
if(key == max){
 key = 0;
}else{
 key++;
}
```

where max is your images count.

But I think there can be easier and better solution in jQuery :)

Comment: What is jQuery, and how would that be easier?

Comment: JQuery is liblary for js and with it everything is easier. I recommend you to learn it :) http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the easiest way to move forward, although it ends up declaring these variables as globals.

```
var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"];
var currentImage = 0; //defaults to image1.jpg

function goNext() {
    currentImage += 1;

    //loop back to the first image
    if(currentImage >= images.length) {
        currentImage = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = images[currentImage];
}
```

So, you would just call goNext() for your button click.

Basically, what's going on here is that an array is a list of items, in this case strings that are a reference to an image somewhere. You can get an item out of the array by indexing it, which is like saying give me the 1st item. In Javascript, that would be images[0].